# Couchdb HTTP 412 Error : missing_stub

Tags: database, couchdb, bulkinsert, http-status-code-412

I'm having an issue with **couchdb 1.2.0** while saving multiple documents using the bulk API.

Request info :
`POST /myCouchDB/_bulk_docs`

Response info :
`HTTP 412 (Error: missing_stub id:customerfile-36975, name:contract)`

This HTTP 412 error occurs randomly, and the document quoted in the error message (ie *customerfile-36975*) changes over time.
An opened issue in CouchDB could be related to this problem : https://github.com/beppu/anyevent-couchdb/issues/7, but hasn't been fixed since Jan 2012...

If someone has any clue or workaround, please tell me !

Comment: Any reason you can't upgrade to the latest version? (`1.6.1`) I'm not saying it's already been fixed, I don't know the changelog well enough, but it's very possible given how long ago `1.2.0` was released.